# Python: Self is not defined

Tags: python

```
class a(object):
 def __init__(self):
         self.b = 1
         self.c = 2
```

This gives the error: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

I looked at a previous post, but the error was for a different reason. Any help with this?

Comment: What you have is valid. We need a more complete picture.

Comment: The code in the question is valid. By the way, class names begin with a capital letter by convention

Comment: @Nathon: I reverted your edit since the indentation is exactly what's wrong with the code, and fixing the indentation makes the question entirely pointless.

Comment: on which line do you get the NameError (yes, I doubt it's too relevant, but...). Please append the full stacktrace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["NameError: name 'self' is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12021511/90527)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm assuming the single space before `def __init__(self):` is actually a tab in your file and displayed as four spaces by your editor.

However python interprets a tab as 8 spaces, so the following two lines (which are indented by 8 spaces) are seen by python to be at the same level of indentation as the `def`.

This is exactly why you shouldn't mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: I think that would give an IndentationError, as the def requires a body.

Comment: He may have sliced out earlier lines to "give the simplest example."

Comment: @Nick: Yes and the earlier lines were indented by two tabs. That must be it.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess because you didn't post the actual traceback or code, but if the actual snippet above is giving you problems, it's probably that your indentation is off and the interpreter is interpreting your scoping levels incorrectly.

Comment: Rats, sepp2k types way faster than I do apparently :)