# "NameError: name 'self' is not defined"

Tags: python

I'm sure it has to do with with tabs/spaces, but the $1 million question is where in the program???

```
import webapp2

form="""
<form method="post">
    What is your birthday?
    <br>

    <label> Month
    <input type="text" name="month">
    </label>

    <label> Day
    <input type="text" name="day">
    </label>

    <label> Year
    <input type="text" name="year">
    </label>
    <div style="color: red">%s(error)s</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
"""
months = ['January', 'Febuary','March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
mapping = dict((m[:3].lower(), m) for m in months)

def valid_month(month):
    if month:
        s_month = month[:3].lower()
        return mapping.get(s_month)

def valid_day(day):
    if day and day.isdigit():
        day = int(day)
        if day in range(1, 32):
            return day

def valid_year(year):
    if year and year.isdigit(): 
        int_year = int(year)
        if int_year in range(1900,2021): 
            return year

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write_form(self, error=""):
        self.response.out.write(form % {"error": error})

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()

    def post(self):
        user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))

        if not (user_month and user_day and user_year):
            self.write_form("That's wasn't valid, friend!")
        else:
            self.response.write("Thanks! That's a totally valid day!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Comment: At which line is `self` not defined?

Comment: All the 'self's in there look valid. can you just give us the offending part of the script (the function with the line that throws the exception)? I suspect  typo...

Comment: self not defined in "user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))"

Answer (score 3):

`python -tt` will tell you where.

```
$ python -tt script.py
  File "script.py", line xxx
    ...
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define valid_month, valid_day, and valid_year within the class.

When you call them you need to say

```
 user_month = self.valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
```

instead of

```
 user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
```

and in each definition of each method, you need to include 'self' as the first parameter, so that it will bind to the class:

```
def valid_month(self, month):
```

instead of

```
def valid_month(month):
```

Otherwise, "self" as the class is being referred to, means nothing to these extraneous methods that exist outside the class scope.